# Using a string as the input stream to execute_process

Tags: shell, cmake, piping

IN CMake (3.x), the `execute_process` command has an `INPUT_FILE` named parameter, which lets you redirect the input stream to come from a file on disk. Well, what about a string? How can I get the command's input to come from a string?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing right now is basically:

```
execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "echo \"${MY_STRING}\" | /path/to/actual/command")
```

but I don't like it :-(

Comment: Instead of '|' it is better to use *COMMAND* keyword: in `execute_process` commands are actually piped. Also, if a cross-platform way is wanted, there is `cmake -E echo`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I'm not following. Can you explain how commands are piped? Perhaps just write it up as an answer? Also, what is `cmake -E echo` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of the [answer with echo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48998233/3440745):

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "${MY_STRING}"
    COMMAND /path/to/actual/command
)
```

Here:

- `${CMAKE_COMMAND}` is expanded to absolute path to `cmake`
- `cmake -E echo` is a CMake analogue for a shell's `echo` command but cross-platform
- several *COMMAND*'s in `execute_process` are piped: an output of the first command is an input of the second command